# Which side do we place a node if it is equal to the parent in a binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am learning data structures and algorithms. In particular, I am learning Binary Search Trees (BSTs).

My question, as the title hints, is, if we are placing a value, and it is equal to its parent, which side do we place it? The left side is for values lesser than the parent, and the right side is for values greater than the parent. So, where do we place a value equal to the parent?

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: We can insert node with value same as parent on either side. I prefer inserting it on the right side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn’t a universally agreed upon standard way to do this. Some people don’t allow BSTs to store duplicates at all, essentially defining this problem away. (That’s what you often see when using trees for maps and sets). Other implementations might store all equal keys in the same node, perhaps by using a linked list. Others might say that the left subtree holds smaller keys while the right subtree holds keys greater than or equal to the node’s own key.

Each of these approaches has advantages and disadvantages, and it’s up to you to select which one is best for your use case.

Comment: Note: Many languages that have the concept of comparators use a default of `operator<`, which means equal values are treated the same as greater values. (AKA: insert on the right)

Comment: @Mooing Duck, yes, I noticed this with my code. Even without checking for equal values, it inserts it on the right (I use Python 3.9.2)

Comment: @templatetypedef, Thanks for explaining in carefully and considerately!

Answer (score 2):

Algorithms just make the choice on which side to insert a value that is the same as the current node has. It is of course easiest (and cost effective) to implement when that choice is always the same.

However, binary search trees can only guarantee logarithmic efficiency when they maintain some balance, and so we must also consider what rebalancing does to the position of nodes that have the same value.

For instance, if the binary search tree is an AVL tree, then rotations will occur when there is an imbalance of more than 1 in any subtree.

Let's assume we have an algorithm for an AVL tree that chooses the right side when a value is equal to the current node's value. And let's say we insert the values 1, 1 and 2 in that order in an empty tree. Then after the second insertion, we get this:

```
  1
   \
    1 (insert at right side of root)
```

Then we insert 2:

```
  1
   \
    1
     \
      2
```

Now the AVL mechanics perform a simple left rotation, and we end up with:

```
  1
 / \
1   2
```

...and now the second inserted node became the root, putting the original root at its *left* side.

So, in conclusion, when we speak of an *self-balancing* binary search tree, then even when the algorithm chooses one specific side for inserting a duplicate value, there is no guarantee that all equal values are always *found* at that side, due to the rebalancing feature of the tree.

Comment: WOW! very detailed and moderately easy to understand. Thanks for that!

Comment: Oh no, nothing is wrong with your answer. It is just that the first answer is easier for me to understand. Sorry if I have caused any offence.

Answer (score 1):

As @templatetypedef mentioned, one common approach is to only allow a single node for each value (i.e. key) in the BST. For multiset semantics (to keep track of how many times a key is present) it is sufficient to store a counter at each node. This approach is simple and quite efficient.

Comment: Thank you! As @templatetypedef mentioned, this eliminates the question (or problem) straight away. Thank you for taking the time to answer!